# phonegap LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT locate file on device

Tags: android, file, cordova, filesystems

I am using phonegap to create a txt file on the user's device.
I am using LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, and I would like to know on android samsung G4 - 4.4.2, where the file is actually created.

In fact does the file really exists as a real file ? or is this file included in a custom dll that only phonegap can access ?

I think it's in data/data
But for me it's not there.

PS : I also have astro manager to try to locate the file but so far no luck
( I am also turning on the "show hidden files" feature )
here are the places I looked into

```
sdCard0: Android/data/(my app folder)/cache  >>empty
sdCard0: Android/data/(my app folder)/files  >>empty
sdCard0: Documents/   >>empty
extSdCard: Documents/   >>empty
root: >> empty
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: it does exist as a real file for sure. But are sure that the file got created without any errors before looking for it? As far as i know, when i was working on Android 5, it wasn't allowing me to create files under Android/data/<myapp> folder as it required root access. Ended up using cordova.file.externalRootDirectory.

Comment: It deppends on the version of the file plugin that you use and the way you configured it. Provide those details

Comment: Thanks for the tip Gandhi, I will check that